# A way to translate JS with Poedit

Tags: javascript, php, internationalization, gettext

I´m translating strings in PHP with Gettext and Poedit software.
I would like to use translated strings also in JavaScript, but without putting the code inline into HTML-documents, but in external files. Inline in HTML-documents it would be no problem because the inline JS-code is also rendered. An example:

```
var hello = <?=_("hello");?>
```

The translator should use the same translation-tables as the php-code does (because of duplicate strings).

So my idea was to "compile" the JavaScript files with PHP. For example in an external JS-file is this code:

```
if (window.confirm("_translate('are_you_sure')")) {
location.href = this.href;
}
```

A php script reads this code above and finds all strings inside `_translate()`. The code will replace `_translate('are_you_sure')` with the translated string.
It works but is never translating, because the Poedit software will not find the string in `_translate()` even if I add _translate into the keys of the source. So there is no translated strings to be translated.

So my question is how to tell Poedit that he should read strings with `_translate()` inside a javascript-file?

Comment: This isn't exactly that you want, but seems to be util: http://i18next.com/

Answer (score 0):

you could include a php script, which do the translations in the javascript file

```
$js = $_GET['js'];

// security check
if (preg_match('~[^a-z0-9_-]~', $js)) {
    die("invalid js");
}

$content = file_get_contents('path_to_js/' . $js . '.js');
preg_match_all('~_translate\(\'([^\']+)\'\)~', $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    $content = str_replace($match[0], _($match[1]), $content);
}
echo $content;
```

so you have to include instead of `yourscript.js` the php file `script.php?js=yourscript`

Comment: that's what I meant by "A php script reads this code above and finds all strings inside _translate(). The code will replace _translate('are_you_sure') with the translated string.".

The problem is also in your example: Poedit will not find _($match[1]) and the strings are therefore not in the list to translate.

Comment: You know the problem is not to replace _translate() with the translated string. The problem is that Poedit will not find the content inside _translate() and therefore I can not translate it in the program.

Comment: You have to add an parser definition under file->settings

Comment: Okay here we go:
In my catalog settings I have added the key _translate so that the parser will find the string "are_you_sure" I have posted above:
http://s1.directupload.net/file/d/3325/gb2z6ary_jpg.htm
I also added *.js in the file-types to parse:
http://www.directupload.net/index.php?mode=upload

Poedit didn´t find the string. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Wrong link to the second picture?

Comment: You´re right, sorry! Updated link: http://s7.directupload.net/file/d/3325/nnpnk4nu_jpg.htm

Comment: Create a new parser for js and dont use the php parser. Also change the language from php to python or perl(javascript isn't supported)

Comment: Thanks, I used Python and it worked well. The only problem left is that the parser will find a lot of warnings in jquery and jquery ui: "unterminated string". Is there a way to restrain this warnings by editing the parser settings for python?

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is how to tell Poedit that he should read strings with _translate() inside a javascript-file?

Add the `_translate` keyword (which is a non-default one for JS) to the keywords list and add the path to your .js file. That's it. Poedit/xgettext supports JavaScript for quite some time now.

You misdiagnosed your problem, though, and Poedit's JS support isn't it. The real problem is that you're expecting Poedit/xgettext to parse a *string literal* that happens to contain some code. `"_translate('are_you_sure')"` is not JavaScript code (that xgettext could find the `_translate` function in) in your example above — it's a *string!* And you're asking the `confirm()` function to display it including the "_translate" bit, it makes no sense.

You wouldn't have that problem with code like this:

```
msg = _translate('are_you_sure');
if (window.confirm(msg)) {
  location.href = this.href;
}
```

(Of course, you have to ensure *client-side* JS gettext deployment, including access to MO files, then, which is more work then translating strings on the PHP side.)